# RadioButton React Native Paper set IOS style in android

Tags: android, react-native, radio-button, react-native-paper

I'm using `RadionButton` from `react-native-paper` library. For android I have such style [image]

Is it possible to set `RadioButton` style in Adroid such as IOS style (icon "checked")? Thanks in andvance for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below code

```
<RadioButton.IOS
    status={status}
    onPress={onPress}
/>
```

more docs in here https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/radio-button-ios.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but after this I have some problems with font icon

Comment: you must install `react-native-vector-icons` to get this icon